# barryvdh/laravel-cors specific route issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3 & having issue using middleware CORS for specific route.
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Below code works fine if I want to allow CORS for all your routes.

```
protected $middleware = [
     \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

But I wanted to use on specific route so I added it to $routeMiddleware in app/Http/Kernal:

```
  protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'cors'=>\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

And then in the route file.

```
Route::get('test6',['middleware'=>'cors','uses'=>'AbcController@test6']);
```

It generated CORS error so probably middleware is not being applied properly in case of $routeMiddleware

Comment: Have you published the config as mentioned in the docs like so: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"`

Comment: yes, I run this command again and got "publishing complete for tag"  message

Comment: Sorry, I know this isn't an answer to the question you asked, but that CORS package doesn't actually handle all the logic necessary to truly handle cross-domain requests.  I'm pretty sure PUTs and POSTs can even still go through if they aren't preceded with an OPTIONS call that'd tell the requestor not to send them.  I'd recommend Neomerx: https://github.com/neomerx/cors-psr7.